# JQuery .length of element(s) inside each() function

Tags: jquery

Assuming I have the following HTML

```
<div class="news_item">
    <div class="news_content">Some Content Here...</div>
    <img src="something.jpg" />
</div>
```

I have the following JQuery code; which is suppose to count how many IMG elements there are within the particular DIV and change the CSS of DIV.news_content if there are *no* IMG elements.

```
$('div.news_item').each(function() {
        if ($('img', this).length == 0) {
        $('div.news_content', this).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
    }
});
```

However $('img', this).length does not seem to work inside the each function.

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/rJWHY/).

Comment: Seems to work when I test it in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vbw4H/  What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox. Thanks for the response guys, I will have to double check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like it's working, but here is some alternative code that filters out any div's with img children.

```
$('div.news_item').not(function(index){return $(this).find('img').length > 0;}).each(function(index, elem){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$(this).find('img').length`

Comment: what about `$(this).children("img").length` ?

Comment: children would go only one level deep, find drills down on all levels

Comment: yeah, but its inside a `each` so, one level deep per every `div.new_item` selected. Also, depends of the _DOM_, but it looks like _children_ could be more efficient in this case.

Comment: true, if you are looking for images only in the direct children, then `children` would be more efficient. depends on dom

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as is. Make sure you don't have invalid HTML or are looking incorrectly and spotting an image in a sibling element.

Comment: Hmm, strange I will check my HTML.